# Embedding Ruby code in HTML?

Tags: ruby

In PHP, it is possible to do this:

```
<input type="text" value=" <?php echo "Hello world"; ?> ">
```

Is it possible to embed Ruby in HTML like that with or without Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use a templating engine like Ruby Templates (ERB). Here's an [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20090119140501/http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1723). Rails uses ERB so you could easily do this in each of your templates.

Comment: Original link was dead (expected 10+ later).  I replaced with the archive.org version

Answer (score 1):

Rails has something called [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html) to do just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) for HTML templating, otherwise ERB.