# Using Ruby and HTML together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to put Ruby code in the HTML page which has a extension ".rhtml"?

For example, I want to use a HTML form and then some Ruby code. Does it have to be encapsulated in the `<%` tags?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486664/embed-ruby-code-in-html

Answer (score 2):

".erb" is what you are looking for. Rails uses ".erb" files and it is possible to embed Ruby code inside them.

Answer (score 2):

The file extension should be ".html.erb" for Rails 3 or above.

The Ruby code should be between `<% %>` for logic statements, or between `<%= %>` if you want to display the results of the code.